# R 'mvrt' package - how to install on Mac?

Tags: r, devtools, install.packages

I am trying to install the 'mvrt' package on my Mac (macOS 14.2). I know that the package was archived. I have been trying to install the archived version of the package on GitHub.

I tried:

```
devtools::install_github("cran/mvpart")
```

What I get:

```
Downloading GitHub repo cran/mvpart@HEAD
── R CMD build ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/cs/mymgkcr962bfp5yw2hz0_p0c0000gn/T/RtmpKAmzol/remotes1385375c47cd/cran-mvpart-acf0035/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  preparing ‘mvpart’:
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information
─  cleaning src
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  building ‘mvpart_1.6-2.tar.gz’
   
* installing *source* package ‘mvpart’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
using C compiler: ‘Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)’
using SDK: ‘’
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/opt/R/arm64/include    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c anova.c -o anova.o
In file included from anova.c:6:
./rpart.h:37:5: error: unknown type name 'Sint'; did you mean 'int'?
    Sint   *numcat;        /* variable type: 0=cont, 1+  =#categories */
    ^~~~
    int
./rpart.h:38:5: error: unknown type name 'Sint'; did you mean 'int'?
    Sint   **sorts;             /* allocated on the fly */
    ^~~~
    int
2 errors generated.
make: *** [anova.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mvpart’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/mvpart’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/cs/mymgkcr962bfp5yw2hz0_p0c0000gn/T//RtmpKAmzol/file1385b6e0020/mvpart_1.6-2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have installed Xcode through my computer's terminal and made it was updated and am still getting the same error message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This looks like a compatibility problem between source `c` code and the compiler in use.  I suggest you post this question to the r-sig-mac mailing list, as folks there are experts in compiler vs. Xcode vs.  source problems.    Or, of course post as bug report to the github repository directly.